# Connect Android To Hana Database

Tags: android-studio, hana

I am trying to connect my android program to Hana database using jdbc driver.
It was running well when try to connect to SQL database server. But I when try to connect to Hana database, it cannot be connected.
I have added jdbc in my library, and also added some permission in android. But it does not work. The database could be connected.

Here's java code the I used.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

private static String ip = "172.10.x.x";
private static String port = "xxxx";
private static String Classes = "com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver";
private static String db = "DBTEST";
private static String usr = "databaseuser";
private static String pass = "databasepassword";
private static String url = "jdbc:sap://"+ip+":"+port+"/?databaseName="+db+"&user="+usr+"&password="+pass+";";
private Connection connection = null;

public void connectButtonClick(View v){initializeMainComponents();}

public void initializeMainComponents()
{
try {
      Class.forName(Classes);
      DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(5);
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usr,pass);
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Database connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } 
catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Database connection error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
catch(SQLException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Database connection failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
  }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the issue that you are encountering? e.g. do you receive an error message?

Comment: @MathiasKemeter : The error message that I've got is Database connection error. It always 
 throws to catch(ClassNotFoundException e). When I try to debug my android program, it crashed on the Classes (com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver).

Comment: Have you added `ngdbc.jar` to your class path? Details can be found here: https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/0eec0d68141541d1b07893a39944924e/ff15928cf5594d78b841fbbe649f04b4.html

Comment: @MathiasKemeter : I already tried to add ngdbc.jar in my class path, but when I try to debug the program, I got an information from logcat it said "I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation".